# Accessing data from within multiple functions

Tags: php

Where I have 3 calculations I need to access in multiple functions, is there a better option than using functions, like:

```
public function shipping()
{
    // Calculate shipping into $shipping

    return $shipping;
}

public function tax()
{
    // Calculate tax into $tax

    return $tax;    
}

public function total()
{
    // Calculate total into $total

    return $total;  
}
```

Then calling:

```
$this->shipping();
```

I have read that global variables are best avoided.

Comment: Do you want to avoid multiple function , If so you can use single function and return values for tax, shipping etc as an associated array. I have added a sample code for that below

Comment: You can also chain your functions.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you need / what you'd like to do with this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to reduce the function calls

```
public function getProductCalculations($productId){
    $return = array()
    // Calculate total into $total
    // Calculate tax into $tax
    // Calculate shipping into $shipping
    $return['tax']      = $tax;
    $return['shipping'] = $shipping;
    $return['total']    = $total;
    return $return;  
}
```

Then you can get data as given below

```
$productCalc = $this->getProductCalculations($productId);
```

Comment: I was hoping to find an alternative which allows me to call each of the calculations without having to pass them into a variable first. So instead of $productCalc['tax'] after setting the array to $productCalc, I could simply call $productCalc->tax or similar.